# Counting how many Lottery draws it takes for a range of numbers to appear

Tags: excel, vba

I'm practicing coding and as a Lottery player I thought I might dive into coding by making code in Excel VBA that counts how many draws a certain number I marked as "x" takes to appear and saves the number in "Counter" that increments whenever it doesn't find it. When it's found, it saves it in a cell I mark by "LineN" and "RowN" cursors and then it resets the "Counter" to zero, the "Line" increments to move from one draw to the next.

By the way, I play a 6/49 lottery and I have a list of 1667 draws.

**First faulty code** :

```
Sub Module1()
Dim Line As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim LineN As Integer
Dim RowN As Integer
LineN = 1674
RowN = 2
Line = 3
Counter = 0
x = 1
Do Until Line > 1669
A = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 2).Value
B = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 3).Value
C = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 4).Value
D = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 5).Value
E = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 6).Value
F = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 7).Value
    If A = x Or B = x Or C = x Or D = x Or E = x Or F = x Then
        Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(LineN, RowN).Value = Counter
        RowN = RowN + 1
        Line = Line + 1
        Counter = 0
    Else
        Counter = Counter + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

**Current code** : I fixed and edited my code a little bit to make it look for values ranging from 1 to 49 and place the results where the incrementing cursor `LineN` is pointing at, but for some reason it doesn't work, it only looks for the first value "1" and displays the results on the Excel sheet then it stops, meaning `x` isn't incrementing and `LineN` as well, it's as if the loop isn't working for some weird reason.

Any ideas ?

```
Sub Module1()
Dim Line As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim LineN As Integer
Dim RowN As Integer
LineN = 1674
RowN = 2
Counter = 0
    For x = 1 To 49
            For Line = 3 To 1669
                A = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 2).Value
                B = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 3).Value
                C = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 4).Value
                D = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 5).Value
                E = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 6).Value
                F = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Line, 7).Value
                If A = x Or B = x Or C = x Or D = x Or E = x Or F = x Then
                    Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(LineN, RowN).Value = Counter
                    RowN = RowN + 1
                    Line = Line + 1
                    Counter = 0
                Else
                    Counter = Counter + 1
                    Line = Line + 1
                End If
            Next Line
            LineN = LineN + 1
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: A `Do ... Loop` doesn't stop until the condition is met or `Exit Do` is used. Take `Line = Line + 1` out and have it before `Loop` should when `Line = 1669`. However `x` is never changed within the loop. You do need to becareful when doing nested loop. If there is no need to continue once a condition is met, you can use `Exit For` to jump out of that For loop to improve performance. Add `DoEvents` at end of loop to make Excel more responsive when looping seems to cause Excel to hang.

Comment: Are you trying to determine how many random draws of 6 numbers it takes to match one of your 1669 lotto tickets? Sorry if I missed your intent completely.

Comment: @PatricK Sorry i guess my question is a mess, forget about the first code, the second code does what the first code was intended for, but when i tried to add an extra feature to my second code so it would go from a range of values (1 to 49) and count how many draws it takes for any value from that range to appear in my list of draws (1667 draws) it didn't work at all, it just looks for the startup value which is "1", gives its results and then the code is done, as if the loop `For x = 1 To 49` isn't even there !
I'll try `DoEvents` and report back, thank you.

Comment: @KacireeSoftware No, I have a list of all the previous draws which are 1667, I have them on an Excel sheet.
I'm trying to determine how many draws it takes for any value going from 1 to 49 to appear in my list of draws, so for example when `x = 1` my code will look for number 1 in my list of draws and it keeps count of how many draws that didn't have the number 1 in them and saves the count in `Counter`, and whenever that value is found, the `Counter` saves its value in a cell on my Excel sheet then it gets reset to zero allowing it to continue looking and doing the same process again.

Comment: Ahh ok i gotcha!

Comment: You are incrementing Line but you are using LineN. I think the LineN in this part should ve Line.  Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(LineN, RowN).Value = Counter

Comment: Sorry im on my phone and its a pain to comment well here.

Comment: Scratch that. You need to really look at how you use Line and LineN. Line will increment once for each draw. You should NOT be incrementing it in your code without reason (you skipping draws that way). It will automatically increment when the NEXT statement runs

Comment: @KacireeSoftware Thanks a lot, i was super dumb and blind, i corrected the mistake you mentioned and after focusing on my code i finally found my issue, i forgot to add a line of code to reset `RowN` to its initial value which is "2", i reworked my code and fixed everything, now it's working flawlessly, you can check it out below, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to post the final code that thanks to all the answers above is working now flawlessly and as intended, you can check it out below.

```
Sub Module1()
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim ColN As Integer
Dim Col As Integer
Dim RowN As Integer
RowN = 1674
ColN = 2
Counter = 0
    For x = 1 To 49
        For Row = 3 To 1669
            A = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Row, 2).Value
            B = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Row, 3).Value
            C = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Row, 4).Value
            D = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Row, 5).Value
            E = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Row, 6).Value
            F = Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(Row, 7).Value
            If A = x Or B = x Or C = x Or D = x Or E = x Or F = x Then
                Worksheets("Sheet12").Cells(RowN, ColN).Value = Counter
                ColN = ColN + 1
                Counter = 0
            Else
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If
        Next Row
        RowN = RowN + 1
        ColN = 2
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a different direction to attack the problem

create an array `n(49)` and init to zero

the array elements hold the draw# for each of the 49 numbers possible ( six array elements get updated at each draw with the drawn numbers being used as an index into the array)

each time a number is drawn then the corresponding array element is retrieved and checked (last draw# it was drawn)

that value gets subtracted from the current draw# and the difference is recorded as per your code

then the current draw# replaces the previous draw# in the array element

example: number 8 gets drawn in draw #1 and draw #14

```
draw# 1 ...  8,12,21,26,31,44   .... n(8)=1, n(12)=1, n(21)=1, n(26)=1, n(31)=1, n(44)=1
draw# 2 ...  2, 6,23,35,36,39   .... n(2)=2, n(6)=2,  n(23)=2, n(35)=2, n(36)=2, n(39)=2
  .
  .
draw #14...  1, 3, 8,11,13,14   .... n(1)=14, n(3)=14,  n(8) was 1, so record the difference of 13 and update n(8)=14
```

that way you are checking only six numbers at each draw

Comment: Thank you for your input, i think you misunderstood my question, probably due to me not phrasing it better, sorry English isn't my mother tongue.
Anyway i did fix my code and it's working now as intended.

Comment: no, i did not misunderstand. your code does something similar, except that you are checking 1667 draws 49 times   ... my suggestion is for checking 6 numbers 1667 times by checking only the drawn numbers

Comment: I still insist that you misunderstood me, you said "by checking only the drawn numbers" but you see, i only have the drawn numbers, which are listed in 1667 draws, i have the data and i'm just checking it for patterns, i have the history of all the draws done in this Lottery game i'm playing, i made a list of them, anyway thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome. i think that i did not explain the process correctly